# Changing font size, but only for ceratin cells

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm getting a syntax error for the if statement. It would be great, if someone could tell me what im doing wrong.

What I'm trying to do is change the text font size to 14 when im editing a certain cell. But the problem now is that i only need certain cells to be font size 14. Every 5 the row starting at A3 should be font size 14.

So:
A3  - font size 14
A8  - font size 14
A13 - font size 14
A18 - font size 14
A23 - font size 14
A28 - font size 14
and so on

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getA1Notation().substr(range.getA1Notation().length-1, range.getA1Notation().length)) == "3" || range.getA1Notation().substr(range.getA1Notation().length-1, range.getA1Notation().length)) == "8") {
    var cell = sheet.getRange(range)
    cell.setFontSize(14);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your super long condition can be reduced to `range.getRow() % 5 == 3`

Ostensibly the Range in the event Object is copied by value not reference so you can't just say `e.range.setFontSize(14)` but it should be the equivalent of the active range unless you are doing something very fast.

The reason it's not setting the correct font Size is that you are feeding it a range as a range argument where it has to be indices or A1 Notation.

In short you can shorten your code to

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getRow() % 5 == 3) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setFontSize(14);
  }
}
```

or

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getRow() % 5 == 3) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()).setFontSize(14);
  }
}
```

if you want to be really sure.

Comment: Oh wow, why did i not think about modulo.
But it doesnt seem to be working.
When i try to run the first example it gives me an error:
"property "range" of undefined cant be read" (translated from german, not sure if its the correct error message in english)
And the same error also pops up when i try to run the second example.

thanks a lot though :)

Comment: Are you running the script from the Script editor or are you actually doing edits? If you are running it from the script editor there is no event object passed that could be read from. Try actually changing something in your spreadsheet.